# The col-sm doesn't work when I have a col-md

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make some html responsive using bootstrap. On the desktop view the bootstrap grid works 
just fine but when I switch to smaller screens the `sm` version does not respond. I've observed that when I 
use `col-sm` and `col-md` together the `col-md` kind of overlaps the `sm` properties on the small screens. Plz help!

the html code:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row class_1">  
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
        <img class="img-class">
     </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 class_2 ">
        <span>text</span>
        <span>text</span>
    </div>
    <div class=" clas_2 class_3 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <span>text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css in case of some other class interferes

```
.class_1{
    color:white;
    padding:20px;

    .img-class{
        width:220px;
        height:auto;
    }

    .class_2{
        text-align:center;
        display: flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
        align-content: flex-end;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        font-size: 15px;
        flex-direction: row;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
    .class_3{
        font-size: 19px;
        justify-content:flex-end;
    }   
}
```

Comment: why is the CSS nested? are you using SASS? The HTML is missing a closing tag too.

Comment: working fine https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/23Lupwxq/4/

Comment: Yes I'm trying sass, it seems quite usefull

Comment: add meta tag on your head tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Thanks! The <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> solves the issue! I'll check about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I should add the solution to the issue. Thanks to  @Lalji Tadhani's helpfull comment the solution is that I simply missed the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` on my html head....:-S

Comment: This saves my day.

Answer (score 0):

Hi according to bootstraps docs version 4.3 for mixing and matching have you tried just `class="col-6 col-md-4"`

See docs here :- https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#mix-and-match

Hope this helps

Comment: No sadly this does not work either...  thanks for the response though.

Comment: Oh :( Hope you get it sorted :/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row class_1">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <img class="img-class">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 class_2 ">
                <span>text</span>
                <span>text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 clas_2 class_3 ">
                <span>text</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks fot the instant reply but I made an initial mistake that I changes a few minutes later. The img div is supposed to be a col-12 in sm. I'm really sorry for the fuzz.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the bootstrap columns, just image class can't get the class value as it was in nesting CSS, just change it as below.

```
.class_1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.img-class {
  width: 220px;
  height: auto;
}
.class_2 {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 15px;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
.class_3 {
  font-size: 19px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Well as it turned out I just hadn't had the viewport meta... I'm new to all this and I am making quite a few trivial mistakes. Thanks for the response though!